# How I can change the database name in DataContext

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql, odbc, datacontext

I created the code which fine work with my production database. But I want easy way for changing database name. It is way will be without further action, and code duplication. How I can do it?

I having databeses "MyDB_1", "MyDB_2" - it is full of copies of databases for testing and like that.

The way to change the connection via ODBC is also nice. But how i can do it?

```
 DataTrackerClassesDataContext ctx = new DataTrackerClassesDataContext();

// !!! I cant change the property because it's readonly:
//ctx.Connection.Database = "MyDB_1";
//ctx.Connection.Database = "MyDB_2";

Console.WriteLine(ctx.Connection.Database);

var custQuery = 
    from m in ctx.models 
    where m.status == 1 
    select m.id;

foreach (int id in custQuery)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} ", id);
}
```

Comment: It's LINQ to SQL, not two :) btw why do you use it but not Entity Framework?

Comment: That is what your web.config is for.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to switch the database for a datacontext, then in the constructor for a datacontext you would input the new connection string.

You would do it like this to maintain the format:

```
string connectionString = 
        string.Format("Data Source={0};Initial Catalog={1};Integrated Security=True", 
                      serverName, 
                      dataBaseName);

DataTrackerClassesDataContext ctx = new DataTrackerClassesDataContext(connectionString);
```

And you would just replace the connection string based on which database you wanted to use.